# Detachble / Convertible 2in1 with proper Linux/Ubuntu support

Tags: laptop, tablet

Due to the fact that my old EeePC is next to end of life (which was running with Ubuntu for 7 years) I plan to buy a similar small device as replacement.

Thereby, my focus lies in the Detachable/Convertible 2in1 type of tablet. But not the ones were you flip the keyboard 360 degree around. I recoginzed that on most of the current devices the Linux support is very limited and google only gives my results for more than 3 year old devices where it works.

So does anybody can suggest such a device, like the Lenovo Miix 320, which works properly with linux, (some hacks during install are ok, but touch screen, battery state, sound, and Wifi should work) and is state of the art (not a device of pre 2016).

Comment: What do you plan to use it for? Budget? Target size? Any other concerns with the screen, like resolution, refresh rate, or color accuracy? Performance requirements?

Comment: Target size below 13". Main prupose, reading texts, answering e-mail, ssh connections for administration of other systems. Performance... Videos should play and compiling some stuff should also not take ours. Budget, the Surface 3 which is known to work is out of my budget.

Comment: I'll have to put more time into this later, but the HP x2 210 G2 comes to mind.